# How to skip autoIncrement column to write data on mySQL db using JDBC Google Apps Script

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script, sql-insert

I set up an Apps Script program and it needs to save data to database. However, it is not working.

I have tried to use the code from Google Apps Script Documentation but I can't see how to skip the autoIncrementing field named ID and its the primary key as well.

I have used code below.

```
var connectionName = 'frms-db:us-central1:****';
var user = 'rj-**';
var userPwd = 'fEwnj*LAAj3****';
var db = 'CCW_CLR';

var dbUrl = 'jdbc:google:mysql://' + connectionName + '/' + db;

var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);

var stmt2 = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO tblPreInterview '
                               + '(ID, Timestamp, Email, Section4, Section5, Section6, Section7, Pages12_13, MinorsAtHome, FirearmsStoreage, ReferenceType1, ReferenceName1, ReferencePhone1, ReferenceType2, ReferenceName2, ReferencePhone2, ReferenceEmail2, '
                               + 'ReferenceType3, ReferenceName3, ReferencePhone3, ReferenceEmail3, DeptConditions, NoGuarantee, ServicePolicy, NoRefunds, PenaltyPerjury, Authorization) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '
                               + '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

stmt2.setString(2, new Date());
stmt2.setString(3, data.email);
stmt2.setString(4, data.section4);
stmt2.setString(5, data.section5);
stmt2.setString(6, data.section6);
stmt2.setString(7, data.section8);
stmt2.setString(8, data.pages1213);
stmt2.setString(9, data.minors);
stmt2.setString(10, data.storefirearm);
stmt2.setString(11, data.reftype1);
stmt2.setString(12, data.refcon1);
stmt2.setString(13, data.refphone1);
stmt2.setString(14, data.refemail1);
stmt2.setString(15, data.reftype2);
stmt2.setString(16, data.refcon2);
stmt2.setString(17, data.refphone2);
stmt2.setString(18, data.refemail2);
stmt2.setString(19, data.reftype3);
stmt2.setString(20, data.refcon3);
stmt2.setString(21, data.refemail3);
stmt2.setString(22, data.deptcondition);
stmt2.setString(23, data.review_agree1);
stmt2.setString(24, data.review_agree2);
stmt2.setString(25, data.review_agree3);
stmt2.setString(26, data.review_agree4);
stmt2.setString(27, data.review_agree5);
stmt2.setString(28, data.signature);
stmt2.execute();
```

I expect to add data to my SQL database.

Comment: What's with the trailing comma here: `Authorization,) v`. *not working* is a bad description of the problem. Read [mre] again to correct your question.

Comment: Please update the code in your question with the suggestion provided by one of the users (without inserting the ID column). Also, please add the error message you're getting.

Comment: Code is updated.

Comment: I still see "ID" in the prepareStatement function. Also, you didn't post the error.

Answer (score 1):

If the column is auto_incremented, you do not need to provide a value for it. MySQL automatically assigns a new number when you perform an insert where no value is given for that column.

So you should just not specify this column in your `insert`, ie change:

```
var stmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(
    'INSERT INTO tblPreInterview '
    + '(ID, Timestamp, Email, Section4, Section5, Section6, ...
```

To:

```
'INSERT INTO tblPreInterview '
+ '(Timestamp, Email, Section4, Section5, Section6, ...
```

Accordingly you should remove the first parameter.

Comment: I tried that but still it didnt work. Maybe I am missing something with stm2.setString part. :(

Comment: @RJVillamer: *it did not work*: are you getting an error, which one?